# Pig 0.14.0 processing large number of small files

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop-yarn

I need to read a huge number of small files from HDFS using Pig, the Hadoop version is 2.6 (YARN).

The job gets container errors.

I searched around and found that we can set "mapred.job.reuse.jvm.num.tasks" in Hadoop 1.*, and it's not been supported for YARN any more.

So how could we handle this on YARN?